# How to hide the url of the browser's left-bottom corner when a link is hovered

Tags: html, google-chrome, url, firefox, hyperlink

I would like to hide the url showing up, when I hover a link with the cursor. I only want to this on my browser. There are a lot questions about this around the web, but I don't find any working solution. I am looking for a solution for chrome or firefox.

Why am I need to do this? I will present a site demonstration soon, and I don't want the people to recognise the website url, because it is not launched yet. I decided to open the site in a "popup like" windows without address bar, so the only missing part to achieve my goal is to hide the url showing at bottom of the browser.

Do you guys have anything to solve this?

**EDIT :** It would be better to make changes in the browser with some plugin/addon, I don't want to replace all the link in my html markup. But a javascript that solves this with looping at every link, would be fine too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to have an addon called status-4-evar for firefox to achieve this.
[status-4-evar](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/status-4-evar)

Please follow the [url](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/822487) to find more about how to do this.

you can also change the  anchor  tags and replace it with  span  tags.

thanks

Comment: Thank you very much! [this](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/822487#answer-184316) helped me, so I don't really need an addon anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just for your browser (Firefox) you can add

```
statuspanel {display:none!important;}
```

below the `@namespace` line in your `userChrome.css` file

As of version 61 it has changed to:

```
#statuspanel {display:none!important;}
```

In Firefox go to settings click help, click Troubleshooting Information. scroll down a bit and there will be a Open Folder button. Click it to go to your user profile. Open the chrome folder and the `userChrome.css` file should be there. If not just create a folder called chrome. Inside that create a file and call it `userChrome.css`. The file needs to have:

```
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"); /* only needed once */
```

As the first line. Below that add:

```
statuspanel {display:none!important;}
```

Save the file and restart Firefox and you should be good to go.

Answer (score -1):

Put `href='javascript:;'` and try to redirect the page using javascript function `window.location='page.html'.`

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="javascript:window.location=page.html" clas="">Anchor Text</a>
```

or you can use a common function for redirection.

Comment: This is wrong.. It will display `javascript:...;`, not prevent it from showing.

Comment: Yes, you will see the javascript:; on the status bar but not the complete url, anyway then John need to follow the complete javascript solution without any a tag on the page.

Answer (score -3):

you can use an iframe and embed it into another page

you can use this http://www.vincemitchell.me/projects/iframe/