# Hide URL on clicking or on-hover

Tags: php, html, url, logout

```
 <div class="ms-logout-form">
   You are logged in.
    <a class="login_button" href="http://example.com/9045?action=logout&amp;redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F&amp;_wpnonce=33">
      Logout
    </a>
</div>
```

This is my code.

When i click or hover on Logout,

It shows URL like this-
[image]

How can i hide that or if i cant hide then want to replace that for security purpose.

Comment: See question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520474/how-to-hide-the-url-of-the-browsers-left-bottom-corner-when-a-link-is-hovered

Comment: I think it shows the href of <a> tag. Use form to replace it. Of course use POST method.

Comment: They will see that link in their url when they click it, so even if you hide it (think you can do that with javascript). Might want to have a different approach.

Comment: How is the link appearing? Is it a tooltip as part of the browser? If it is, the only way not to have the tooltip is to not include the link in the first place. However, if you are looking to hide the link like that for security purposes, you are doing this incorrectly because anyone can see the code in the page if they want. Don't include sensitive data if it is not secure.

Comment: is the url is a security, issue, you have bigger problems

Comment: Just 1. Remove the href 2. Make an onclick event that changes the href or  the onclick just sends to a new url.

Comment: Its showing in the bottom of browser

Answer (score 2):

Try following code.

```
<div class="ms-logout-form">
  You are logged in.
   <a class="login_button" onclick="location.href = 'http://example.com/9045?action=logout&amp;redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F&amp;_wpnonce=33'">
  Logout
</a>
```

Comment: It may prevent form hover but when click then the link is shown at address bar.

Comment: If you want to hide some part of url then you can set them in session. by that way you wont need it to specify each time in URL

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be more secure.

```
<form name = "testform" method="post" action="http://example.com/9045">
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="logout">
  <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F">
  <input type="hidden" name="wpnonce" value="33">
  <input name = "submit" type = "submit" value = "Logout">
</form>
```

at the http://example.com/9045/index.php file add this to show the values-

```
<?php 
  echo $_POST["action"];
  echo $_POST["redirect"];
  echo $_POST["wpnonce"];
?>
```

I do it for the better security purpose. You can try it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to direct the user to a page from a url that's in the page content, then it's always going to be accessible one way or another (such as if the user views the page source), whether it's shown or not. A logout link's url really shouldn't be a security concern.

However, If you really don't want that visible to the user, then you could use some JavaScript to add an on-click action to the link that changes `document.location`, but that code (and the url to redirect the user to) will still be in the page content. That might look something like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:window.location='(your logout url)'">Logout</a>
```

Even then, the user is going to see the url briefly when the window.location changes, so it really shouldn't be something you should worry about.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery just bind a click event on the **a** tag. Try this,

```
<div class="ms-logout-form">
   You are logged in.
   <a class="login_button" id="btnLogout">
      Logout
   </a>
</div>
```

Then, for your jQuery code,

```
<script>
$('#btnLogout').on('click', function() {
   location.href("http://example.com/9045?action=logout&amp;redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F&amp;_wpnonce=33");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really really need to serve a page but hiding the URL from `<a>` hover as well as the URL address bar, you can look into serving the page using an iframe. I have done a similar task before and have the code available in this [Github Repository](https://github.com/williamli/MagicFrame).

What you are looking at is something like: http://codepen.io/williamli/pen/adWKmQ

```
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
```

You can use CSS to style the height and width of your iframe to make it look like a native page.