# browsers - hide tooltip for link suggestion by browser

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, cross-browser, epiphany

[image]

I want to hide/disable tooltip for browser which highlighted in images.
When we mouse over on links or loading web page information showing in tooltips but I don't need in my device. so I want to disable it.

No addon because we use in device screen as browser with full screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520474/how-to-hide-the-url-of-the-browsers-left-bottom-corner-when-a-link-is-hovered

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide the url of the browser's left-bottom corner when a link is hovered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520474/how-to-hide-the-url-of-the-browsers-left-bottom-corner-when-a-link-is-hovered)

Comment: @MartinZhai : it dont solve my problem

Comment: @JosiahDaniels : it dont solve my problem. I want disable or hide this tool tip from browser because I using browser for device screen.